# How to get the number of days of a specific calendar week belonging to a particular month using Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to get the exact number of days of a specific calender week but only this one which matches a specific month.

For example: Calender week 48 has 3 days in November and 4 days in December. I only want to get the number of days of December.

I tried this formula but I only get the number of days of the whole week. I dont know how to continue.

```
=WEEKDAY(12/28/2022 ,2) - WEEKDAY(12/04/22 ,2)+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the dates for a specific week_number and month

`=LAMBDA(aix,FILTER(aix,WEEKNUM(aix,2)=49,MONTH(aix)=12))(SEQUENCE(365,1,DATE(2022,1,1),1))`

to get the count of it, wrap it in COUNTA()

`=COUNTA(LAMBDA(aix,IFERROR(FILTER(aix,WEEKNUM(aix,2)=49,MONTH(aix)=12)))(SEQUENCE(365,1,DATE(2022,1,1),1)))`

-

[image]

Comment: Thats funny. It works and I get the right number of days but for the wrong week. It is not 49, its 48. But when I put 48 into the formula it gives me 0. Why?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/v8ab7DU.png || the specific dates you mentioned are week num 49

Comment: Im sry, but this is definitely wrong. But its strange that the formula think its right. Look at some calendar week pages like this for example: https://www.calendar-week.org/calendar-weeks/2022/cw-48

Comment: go for type number 21 in the formula instead of 2. example: WEEKNUM(aix,21)=48